# Is there a better way to shape this async reducer?

Tags: redux, normalization, redux-thunk, reducers

I'm looking for a better way to shape my reducer state using redux. Right now I've this scenario, like a CRUD.

```
export const isFetchingExternalAction = composeAsyncReducer({
  start: FETCH_EXTERNAL_REQUEST,
  done: FETCH_EXTERNAL_SUCCESS,
  fail: FETCH_EXTERNAL_FAILED
});

export const isFetchingList = composeAsyncReducer({
  start: FETCH_LIST_REQUEST,
  done: FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS,
  fail: FETCH_LIST_FAILED
});

export const isFetchingDetails = composeAsyncReducer({
  start: FETCH_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  done: FETCH_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  fail: FETCH_DETAILS_FAILED
});

export const isCreating = composeAsyncReducer({
  start: CREATE_REQUEST,
  done: CREATE_SUCCESS,
  fail: CREATE_FAILED
});

export const isUpdating = composeAsyncReducer({
  start: UPDATE_REQUEST,
  done: UPDATE_SUCCESS,
  fail: UPDATE_FAILED
});

export const isDeleting = composeAsyncReducer({
  start: DELETE_REQUEST,
  done: DELETE_SUCCESS,
  fail: DELETE_FAILED
});

export const errors = (state = Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_SUCCESS:
    case UPDATE_SUCCESS:
      return Map();    

    case CREATE_FAILED:
    case UPDATE_FAILED:
      return fromJS(action.error);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  isFetching,
  isFetchingList,
  isCreating,
  isUpdating,
  isDeleting,
  errors
});
```

This allow me to query by doing something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 isCreating: state.isCreating,
 isUpdatingCreating: state.isUpdating
});
```

My only concern is that this only allow a single entity to be handled.

User goes to page A:
// we are fetching details from page A. So isFetchingDetails will return true.

But if we go to page B while A is being fetched. We will be in trouble. Because A is still being handled. So how can we solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using rxjs? Are you requesting Rx based answers?

Comment: Hi @paulpdaniels, I'm not using Rx but it is welcome!!